# Add dynamic property to class, not instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a way to add a dynamic property to a class (not an instance). Something like Django does with models' managers. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
class Manager:
    def __init__(self, table_name):
        self.table_name = table_name
    # rest omitted for brevity

class BaseModel:
    # somehow create a new instance of Manager
    # and send the init param based off BaseModel's child
    # class table_name Meta property

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        table_name = 'my_table'

MyModel.manager    # should return an instance of Manager(table_name='my_table')
```

I've tried using the constructor (`__new__`), but that obviously only works after I create at least an instance of `MyModel`.

Comment: See [Is there a way to call a method on definition of a subclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57151233/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) for that purpose:

```
class BaseModel:
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        cls.manager = Manager(cls.Meta.table_name)
```

Comment: No idea why I didn't think of this. Thanks!