# Determine if subclass has a base class's method implemented in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, superclass

I have a class that extends a base class. Upon instantiation, I want to check if the subclass has one of the classes implemented from its base, but I'm not sure the best way.  `hasattr(self, '[method]')` returns the method from super if not implemented by the child, so I'm trying to tell the difference.

Here is an example:

```
class Base :
   def __init__ ( self,) :
       pass
   
   def fail (self,) :
       pass

# Now create the subclass w/o .fail
class Task ( Base ) :
    def __init__ ( self, ):
         print( hasattr( self, 'fail' ) ) # < returns True
```

When `Task()` is instantiated it prints  `True` because `Task` inherits `.fail` from `Base`.  But in this case, I want to know that `Task` **Does Not** implement `.fail`, so I want a `False` returned somehow.  It seems like I'm looking for something like `isimplemented( self, 'fail' )`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but it sounds like you *might* be looking for Abstract Base Classes. (Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/S_ipdVNSFlo).) If you specify an `abstractmethod` in a base class that inherits from `abc.ABC`, then attempting to instantiate a subclass will fail unless that subclass overrides the abstractmethod.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def fail(self):
        pass

class Task(Base):
   pass
    
class Task2(Base):
    def fail(self):
        pass

# this raises an exception
# `fail` method has not been overridden in the subclass.
t1 = Task()

# this succeeds
# `fail` method has been overridden in the subclass.
t2 = Task2()
```

If you want a check to happen at *class definition* time rather than *instance instantiation* time, another option is to write an [`__init_subclass__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400284/understanding-init-subclass) method in your base class, which is called every time you subclass your base class or you subclass a class inheriting from your base class. (You don't have to raise an exception in `__init_subclass__` — you could just add a `fail_overriden` boolean attribute to the class, or do anything you like really.)

```
class Base:
    def fail(self):
        pass

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        if cls.fail == Base.fail:
            raise TypeError(
               'Subclasses of `Base` must override the `fail` method'
            )
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)


# this class definition raises an exception
# because `fail` has not been overridden
class Task(Base):
    pass


# this class definition works fine.
class Task2(Base):
    def fail(self):
        pass
```

And if you just want each instance to tell you whether `fail` was overridden in their subclass, you can do this:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print(type(self).fail != Base.fail)

    def fail(self):
        pass

class Task(Base):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
    
class Task2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()

    def fail(self):
        pass

t1 = Task() # prints "True"
t2 = Task2() # prints "False"
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the excellent post.  Option 1 won't work because I don't want the subclass to be required to implement `fail` in this case, I just need to know if it **was** implemented.  Option 2 or 3 seems most likely - I honestly didn't know about `__init_subclass__`. I'll check it out, but the last solution seems most elegant and ultimately matches the use case the most.  Thanks!

Comment: @sadmicrowave great! Glad I could help.

Comment: absolute gem, thanks. Solution #2 for me as I need to check a class that does not get instantiated (SQLAlchemy ORM Tables)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can check `super().fail == self.fail`

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
   
    def fail(self):
        pass

class Task(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print(super().fail == self.fail)
    
class Task2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print(super().fail == self.fail)
    
    def fail(self):
        # Override
        pass
```

Output:

```
t1 = Task()
# True

t2 = Task2()
# False
```

Comment: This makes sense, except in my use case, I would want `t1 = Task()`to return `False` as well.  Because I don't want to explicit have to define `fail` if it is only going to have a `pass` in it...

Comment: So you want to check if subclass has overridden a method of its superclass? perhaps you can just then do `super().fail != self.fail`?

Comment: Does not work if called not from within a constructor. For that use `print(super(type(self), self).fail == self.fail)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly but you could check if `fail` method is in the `vars` of the classes, but not inherited to the main class.

So you could try:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__dir__())
   
    def fail(self):
        pass

class Task(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('fail' not in vars(Task))
    
class Task2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('fail' not in vars(Task2))
    
    def fail(self):
        # Override
        pass
    
t1 = Task()
t2 = Task2()
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Or use `__dict__`:

```
...
class Task(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('fail' not in Task.__dict__)
    
class Task2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print('fail' not in Task2.__dict__)
    
    def fail(self):
        # Override
        pass
...
```